# Chrome not working perfectly with video embedded via video.js

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I am using `videojs` to embed video on the following website: [www.airfixthemovie.com](http://www.airfixthemovie.com). Html video has `preload="none"` which makes it a bit better. Any suggestion on how to make the video to work perfectly in Google Chrome? The trailer stops sometimes in Chrome and it looks like Chrome is loading or buffering. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the network inspector it seems there's something wrong with the backend serving mp4 files. The requests are canceled and there are about 4 requests to the mp4 a second and the Content-Range header seems to throw completely random digits there.

I know this doesn't really answers your question but at least investigate the mp4 thing server side.